# Doxygen skip ifdef

Tags: doxygen, conditional-compilation

I am using doxygen to document my code and I have one concern. I want doxygen to record and disclose the header files. I am using ceedling for my unit tests and I often have to add helper functions for the test code to gain access to data. One of my doxygen headers is as follows.

```
#ifndef INCLUDE_THREAD_HEALTH_H_
 #define INCLUDE_THREAD_HEALTH_H_
  
 #include <stdbool.h>
 #include <stdint.h>
 #include <pthread.h>
  
 #define MAX_TRACKED_THREADS 100U
  
 struct thread_health {
     bool thread_alive;          
     char* thread_name;          
     pthread_t* thread;          
 };
  
 void thread_health_init(void);
  
 int32_t thread_health_create_and_register_thread(pthread_t* thread, pthread_attr_t* attributes, char *thread_name, void *(*ThreadTask) (void *));
  
 bool thread_health_destroy_unregister_thread(const pthread_t* thread);
  
 void thread_health_task(uint32_t period);
  
 #ifdef CEEDLING_TESTS
 struct thread_health thread_health_get_health(uint8_t index);
 #endif
  
 #endif /* INCLUDE_THREAD_HEALTH_H_ */
```

I have the `ifdef` macro, I want doxygen to ignore everything in this macro. I cannot seem to find a way to do this.

Edit: Adding doxygen info

```
# Difference with default Doxyfile 1.8.17
PROJECT_NAME           = "MAIN Application"
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF      = YES
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = YES
RECURSIVE              = YES
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS       = */build/* \
                         */test/*
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
```

My hope was to find an undef option. But that does not seem to exist in Doxygen.

Edit 2: My defined value for my ceedling test helper functions is CEEDLING_TESTS. I would like it if Doxygen could not report the function declarations between this tag.
[image]

Edit 3: I found this in a [FAQ](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/faq.html#faq_code)
[image]
Unfortunately this is not working for me, it may be a version issue. I cannot find a version for the FAQ but I will attempt to update.

Edit 4: I updated to doxygen 1.9.4 following this [guide](https://www.doxygen.nl/download.html). Same issue.

Comment: Which version of doxygen? What is in your settings file different from the default setting (i.e. output of `doxygen -x Doxyfile`)? Where do you see which problem (add an image of the output you got to the question and indicate what is, according to you, not OK.

Comment: Doxygen version 1.8.17 is from December,27 2019, the current version is 1.9.3. You wrote "My hope was to find an undef option" what do you mean by this, when not defined the part between the `#ifdef CEEDLING_TESTS` and `@endif` is not shown in the documentation, it just shows up in the source code files. For this best is to write a dedicated filter (`INPUT_FILTER`) to filter these lines and also to set `FILTER_SOURCE_FILES=YES`

Comment: I want doxygen to see that I have #ifdef CEEDLING_TESTS ... #endif and not include this chunk in the report

Comment: The text mentioned in **Edit 3** only is about the resulting documentation not about the source listings. This is not clear from the description and should be made clear. The source listings give an overview of the source as is (unless filtered as indicated).

Comment: Are you telling me this only works for source files not header files?

Comment: No source files include header files as well.